# Sonarqube how do I get correct command line call

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I assume I am missing something major here but I just started using sonarqube and when I created the project it gave me a command line to run from the project.  I lost that command line call is there a way to retrieve it from the server or do I have to figure out what the arguments were my self and recreate it?

Comment: Hi, do you mean using Sonar Scanner? Then follow docs https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner

Comment: Running the sonnar scanner bat file from the command line

Comment: As I mentioned , check the link above, [also scanner properties](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analysis+Parameters) can be useful

Comment: You can use special commands for maven or gradle projects, etc.. but basic command is just `sonar-scanner`

Comment: Let me understand for which type of project are you trying to run it? is it iOS? Android or what platform it is? What programming language does it contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes for some reason this isn't as easy as you'd expect, mainly because you'll need the token you generated when you created the project. You can regenerate the command line call from the server using the tutorial for your project, so if you had a project called `myproject` and you're running the default docker container on `localhost:9000` then just visit the following url:

`http://localhost:9000/tutorials?id=myproject`